# How should I understand the amount of base current in BJT transistors?

Tags: bjt, transistors

I'm having trouble understanding how much current flows through the base of a BJT. With a MOSFET the answer is easy: 0. How do I calculate the amount of base current in a BJT and am I doing it wrong if my circuit cares?

Comment: What kind of circuit?  Do you want to saturate the transistor (logic circuit, on/off), or use it as an amplifier?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/4/46/BJT_Switch.jpg/800px-BJT_Switch.jpg]
<sub>(source: [wikimedia.org](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/4/46/BJT_Switch.jpg/400px-BJT_Switch.jpg))</sub>

In this circuit, the base current would be approximately (Vs - 0.7) / R2.  The BE junction (with the arrow) behaves like a diode, so as long as Vs is greater than 0.7 V, then current will flow through the diode and there will be a drop of about 0.7 V (depending on the part) and then the current is just limited by the resistor according to Ohm's law.

Comment: I find when building circuits using .7 works a lot better.

Comment: This is one thing that I can really teach well in person, the internet is hard.

Comment: 0.65V is more commonly found on the 'net and is a compromise.

Comment: The exact value varies depending on the part, the amount of current, and the temperature.

Comment: 0.7 volts is for silicon. 0.2 volts for germanium

Comment: All the above answers apply to DC only! For signal base currents we have to consider the differential (dynamic) resistance rbe (instead of Vbe) which, normally is in the lower kOhm range,.

Answer (score 1):

### A functional explanation

The base-emitter junction behaves, like a diode, as a "dynamic resistor" that decreases its resistance when the voltage across it increases and v.v., increases its resistance when the voltage decreases.

So, the input circuit consists of two resistors (constant RB and dynamic RBE that is seen from the input source as differential resistance *rbe*) in series driven by the input voltage source... and the "amount of base current in a BJT" is determined by the dominant resistor having a higher resistance. There are two typical cases:

**Voltage-driven BJT.** If RB << *rbe*, the "amount of base current in a BJT" is determined only by *rbe* according to the input IV characteristic... and it can be graphically solved by the so-called "load line" technique.

**Current-driven BJT.** If RB >> *rbe*, the "amount of base current in a BJT" is determined only by RB... and it can be easily calculated by Ohm's law (look at Glorfindel's answer).

Comment: I am always unhappy when I see that the symbol for a differential resistance is written in capitals (RBE). I think, it is very important always to discriminate between STATIC resistances R (for DC) and dynamic (differential) resistances "r" . Otherwise, misinterpretations are very likely.

Comment: @LvW, Exactly... I perfectly know that... but small letters look bad in the text... this is the reason... Okay, I formatted them in italics. Just to note that for me "dynamic resistance" and "differential resistance" are not the same. The first means "changing ohmic resistance RBE"; the second means "virtual resistance *rbe*" seen by the input source through RB.

Comment: OK - agreed. With other words: "rbe" is for sinusoidal signals only.

Comment: @LvW, ... and for any (both AC and DC) signal change... (it does not depend on time). Very interesting... I continue thinking about this phenomenon.  To realize what the differential resistance 'rbe' means, I suppose that there is an ohmic (static) resistance RBE = VBE/IBE that changes. As a result, the input source "sees" a differential resistance 'rbe' that (almost) does not change. So, the paradox is that RBE is changing while 'rbe' is constant...

Comment: The quantity "rbe" is certainly the inverse slope of the Ib=f(Vbe) characteristic. Together with all the other BJT parameters we also can write rbe=beta/gm with transconductance gm=d(Ic)/d(Vbe) (slope of the Ic=f(Vbe) curve)

Comment: @LvW, I.e., rbe = beta.re since, at the same voltage vbe, when looking at the emitter (CB), we see beta times bigger current than in the case when we look at the base (CE)... But it is still interesting for me to see what you think about my answer to the OP's question in terms of resistances...

Comment: As far as your last sentence is concerned (question), I think there can be no disagreement about the fact that the largest resistor of two resistors in series will mostly determine the current through both. (I assume that in your answer the part RB is an external ohmic part - correct?)

Comment: @LvW, Exactly... RB can be a discrete "base resistor" that belongs to the CE stage (inserted with the purpose e.g. to expand the input voltage range). Or it can be the internal source resistance; in this case, it belongs to the input voltage source. I asked you about this "resistor approach" since usually, it is not used to explain the "amount of base current in a BJT" (OP). It just occurred to me at the moment and I wrote it like this...